List of Future is not executed in parallel
I don't understand why this code is not executed in parallel.
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("db-non-blocking")

println(s"Cores ${Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()}")

def print(i: Int): Future[Unit] = Future {
  if (i == 1) {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
  println(s"Finished $i at ${new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())} (Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName})")
}

Future {
  println(s"${new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())} (Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName})")
  Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}.map(d => {
  d.map(u => print(u))
})

Running this code the output is the following.
Cores 16
Tue Jun 18 14:19:15 CEST 2024 (Thread plugin-system-db-non-blocking-16)
Finished 1 at Tue Jun 18 14:19:20 CEST 2024 (Thread plugin-system-db-non-blocking-16)
Finished 2 at Tue Jun 18 14:19:20 CEST 2024 (Thread plugin-system-db-non-blocking-16)
Finished 3 at Tue Jun 18 14:19:20 CEST 2024 (Thread plugin-system-db-non-blocking-16)
Finished 4 at Tue Jun 18 14:19:20 CEST 2024 (Thread plugin-system-db-non-blocking-16)
Finished 5 at Tue Jun 18 14:19:20 CEST 2024 (Thread plugin-system-db-non-blocking-16)

After the first Future has completed, the map returns a list of Futures. I am confused why the created Futures are not executed asynchronously. All created threads run on the same dispatcher. The pool size of this dispatcher is sufficient to run 5 threads in parallel. It seems, all futures created inside the map function are executed on the same thread.
dispatcher-non-blocking {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 50
  }
  throughput = 1
}

Why are these Futures not executed in parallel and run on the same thread with id 16? If I run this code with different dispatcher, all future get executed in parallel. If the "Seq" is not wrapped inside a future, all created futures run in parallel but why do they run synchronous if created inside map.

Out of interest, what happens if you have blocking { if (i == 1) { Thread.sleep(5000) } println(...) }? (could also wrap the Thread.sleep and println in their own blocking blocks, too)

Basically you're seeing the batching optimization being applied (see also: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12089, though that's about the application of this optimization in Scala's ExecutionContext)

Note that the implementation in the early Scala 2.13 default ExecutionContext is basically the implementation that most Akka dispatchers used and continue to use.

If parallel tasks are wrapped by 'blocking' it seems to work. The tasks are actually running parallel. It seems to be a normal behaviour of nested futures, so to overcome this limitation it's necessary to wrap nested futures with 'blocking'. This seems also be related to the deadlock situation, mentioned here at scala docs. https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/dispatch/BatchingExecutor.html

Seq is processed sequentially. A Future only runs after it is constructed. In this case, using Future.sequence(d.map(u => print(u))) should do the trick.
In scala 2.12 and older,the parallel collection types could work. In 2.13 and 3.x, you will need to add the module to your dependencies.
import scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq

Future {
    println(s"${new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())} (Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName})")
    ParSeq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // <-- ParSeq instead of Seq
  }.map(d => {
    d.map(u => print(u))
  })

Cores 16
Tue Jun 18 12:31:36 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-1)
Finished 2 at Tue Jun 18 12:31:36 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-4)
Finished 3 at Tue Jun 18 12:31:36 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-1)
Finished 4 at Tue Jun 18 12:31:36 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-4)
Finished 5 at Tue Jun 18 12:31:36 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-1)
Blocking 1 at Tue Jun 18 12:31:36 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-3)
Finished 1 after Blocking at Tue Jun 18 12:31:41 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-3)
Finished 1 at Tue Jun 18 12:31:41 EDT 2024 (Thread pool-1-thread-3)


While it offers some alternatives, I don't think this is the answer to OP's question. It is fair to expect OP's code to run on multiple threads. The good answer is the comment from Levi.
